# .htaccess and subdomains

Tags: .htaccess

Hey Folks am seemingly having problems with .htaccess files.

The problem:

I have a wp install in the root directory. In a sub-directory (not a domain) there is Modx. When I enter the url to the root/modx the url is treated like a wp link and it goes back to the homepage. In other words I think the .htaccess is overriding.

The main directory (wp) has this .ht file (after digging around for a solution)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^office/.*$ - [PT]
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

This is the one in the subdirectory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you could add the following rule to your wp .htaccess just before the `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !modx
```

Comment: Nothing happened. Yet when I turned off "RewriteEngine off" it now redirects to "http://ww2.example-domain-please-change.com/500.shtml"